# Send File and receive an object using socket JAVA

Tags: java, sockets

I have here a client and server , Client should send first the File , when the server will receive it , it has to send an Object , 
Sending and receiving file work well , but the client did not receive the result object

```
public class Server_file {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket server_socket = new ServerSocket(2233);
        Socket socket = server_socket.accept();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(
                "C:/Users/Asmaa/Desktop/test51.txt");
        BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int count;
        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
         while((count=in.read(buffer)) >=0 ){
         fos.write(buffer, 0, count);
         }
         fos.close();
         System.out.println("test");
        Resultat res = new Resultat(14);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
        oos.writeObject(res);
        oos.close();
        socket.close();

    }
}
```

And here the client :

```
public class Client_file {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 2233);
        int count;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        File myFile = new File("C:/Users/Asmaa/Desktop/s.txt");

        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                myFile));
        while ((count = in.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, count);
            out.flush();
        }
        System.out.println("hi");
        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
        Resultat to = (Resultat) ois.readObject();
        System.out.println("test");
        System.out.println(to.getA());
        out.close();
        socket.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to send *live* objects across JVM's?  There are without any doubt better solutions to whatever your problem is.

Comment: What do you mean by live object ? it's just an example , server have to do some operation in file and send result Object

Comment: By sending objects the way you do you strongly tie client and server together: eg if you change the `Resultat` class server and client should both be replaced.  Also, as the internal format used to serialize object may change over time, JVM versions should not be overly different between server and client.  All these problems can be avoided by sending eg a JSON-serialized object over the socket.  As an extra benefit, these data will be cleartext which helps tremendously with debugging.